# By most recognised standards—mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, prepositional-phrases

> **By most recognised standards**, management qualifies as a science.

I want to know the actual meaning of the phrase

In which sense "standards" is being used here?

Answer (score 3):

Here, it means something like 'ways of judging whether a subject is an art or a science'.

One of Oxford Languages' definitions of 'standard' is

> something used as a measure, norm, or model in comparative evaluations.
>
> "the wages are low by today's standards"

Comment: "Standard" means in this context—?

Comment: I have added a definition.

Comment: Here,By most recognised standards —means "as per something used as measur or norm or model and  most people accept that  "

Comment: According to most of the usual ways of deciding (whether it's an art or a science), it's a science.,

Comment: While I agree with this answer, I would argue that if the authors used "recognized standards" without any citations, that is a significant omission. "Recognized" here to me suggests a more formal standard that should be citable.